Does it makes sense to DRY a non-async method using its async version?
Trying to do so involves using the weird syntax of GetAwaiter().GetResult().
Beside that fact, it works; but does it sucks to do so? If yes, then why?
Original:
internal static ISector Read(ISector sector, Stream stream)
{
    using var scope = new ArrayPoolScope<byte>(GetLength(sector));

    stream.ReadExactly(scope.Span);

    var result = Read(sector, scope.Span);

    return result;
}

internal static async Task<ISector> ReadAsync(ISector sector, Stream stream)
{
    using var scope = new ArrayPoolScope<byte>(GetLength(sector));

    await stream.ReadExactlyAsync(scope.Memory);

    var result = Read(sector, scope.Span);

    return result;
}

Modified:
internal static ISector Read(ISector sector, Stream stream)
{
    var result = ReadAsync(sector, stream).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    return result;
}

internal static async Task<ISector> ReadAsync(ISector sector, Stream stream)
{
    using var scope = new ArrayPoolScope<byte>(GetLength(sector));

    await stream.ReadExactlyAsync(scope.Memory);

    var result = Read(sector, scope.Span);

    return result;
}


Before you refactor snippet 1 to snippet 2, I'd consider removing the non-async version completely instead of sync-over-async. If that means you have a breaking change, then so be it. But "fake" sync is just lying to consumers.

Btw: I really don't think DRY applies here. It's a different API with a different implementation. It just happens to look very similar.


DRY is not actually about a similar looking code (quite often it is actually the opposite - code which breaks the DRY looks completely different), it is about "knowledge":

Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system

In this case one might argue that there is no piece of knowledge repeated in this to methods, they represent two different things -  reading some data in sync and async way.

I highly recommend to look into the framework code itself. In this particular case into the ReadExactly/ReadExactlyAsync implementations. If you open both you will see that they call ReadAtLeastCore and ReadAtLeastAsyncCore respectfully which have quite similar looking implementations but they are still not implemented in the sync-over-async "sharing" manner.

Check out the Don't Block on Async Code by  Stephen Cleary which explains the potential pitfalls of the sync-over-async implementation which you want to use. In short - it can result in deadlock in some cases and even if it does not it can affect system performance negatively.


TL;DR
No, you should not do this, this arguably does not break the DRY and have potential problems for the users.
